# Mysql Create Table (select) query cross server

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a trouble creating a query that crosses servers.  Here is the query i got but i'm unable to make the connection (yes i left out my DB names on purpose).

```
CREATE TABLE myTargetTable (SELECT * FROM mySourcetable)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case a [FEDERATED storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/federated-storage-engine.html) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you can't run a sql query across two different servers (instances of mysql). You can run a query against multiple databases on the same instance by prepending the name of the db to the tables. In your case, assuming myTargetTable is in db1 and mySourcetable is in db2 the query will be
CREATE TABLE db1.myTargetTable (SELECT * FROM db2.mySourcetable)
but this won't work if db1 and db2 are in two different instances.
Perhaps you can try using mysqldump to dump your table from db1 and load it to db2.